# What does semantic entailment even mean, in the context of completeness?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, definition, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

I tried to prove the soundness of a Hilbert system over in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930250/proving-soundness-property-of-a-hilbert-system) and so now I am trying to prove completeness from the other direction:

$$\Gamma \models \varphi \implies \Gamma \vdash \varphi$$

I read this as "If $\varphi$ is true under all interpretations where $\Gamma$ is satisfied, then we can show that $\varphi$ is provable from $\Gamma$"

But then I realized I don't even know where to begin. We are starting from a position where we don't even have a proof written down. This led me to realize that maybe I don't fully understand semantic entailment. In absence of syntax / axioms / inference rules / etc, I don't even know what this really means.

What are some examples of what this even looks like before we move onto showing provability? **Is this something we are only able to show strictly in terms of truth tables?** (this perhaps the real question I am asking in all this)

For example: If $\Delta = \{p, (p \to q) \}$, can we say $\Delta \models q$? Meaning that when $p$ is true and $p \to q$ is true, then the truth tables suggest that $q$ is true? And then we can show the existence of a proof of $q$ in three lines: $\varphi_1 = p, \varphi_2 = p \to q$ by assumption, and then $\varphi_3 = q$ via modus ponens on $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$?

And then proving completeness is showing that whenever all the statements of $\Delta$ are true and the righthand side is true, we can write a proof for it?

Comment: The completeness property is relative to a *proof system* : language + axioms + rules. It means that the proof system is "enough powerful" to match with the logical consequence relation for the semantics specific for that language.

Comment: The completeness proof is by far more difficult than the soundness one; see math log textbooks.

Comment: See e.g. the post [What is the role of the proof system in a Henkin-proof of Completeness ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463478/what-is-the-role-of-the-proof-system-in-a-henkin-proof-of-completeness)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is my example/usage of ⊨ correct, in understanding what it means for something to be a logical consequence before we even get into proofs?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So if we have $\Gamma \models \varphi$ does this imply that either $\varphi \in \Gamma$ (since $\Gamma$ is satisfied), or $\varphi$ is an axiom, or $\varphi$ is an atomic variable that happens to be true when we map out the truth tables for everything in $\Gamma$? Are those all the cases?

Comment: Not necessarily $\varphi$ atomic. We have e.g. $\{ p \land q \} \vDash p \lor q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But wouldn't that fall into my first case where $\varphi \in \Gamma$? If $\varphi \in \Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ is satisfied then $\Gamma \models \varphi$?

Comment: @user525966 Note "$\wedge$" versus "$\vee$."

Comment: Oh, I missed that, thanks. Good example, makes sense